# Is there a way to store the result of functions that return string in a string during compilation of typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation

I have a couple of typescript functions that link to each other to generate a specific template. I would like to load this template in a another part of my application but I do not want to have it reprocess every time when a client loads the application.

Is there a way where or a library that could turn this typescript file:

```
function a(){
  return "string1"
}

function b(){
  return "string2"
}

function join(){
  return a + b
}

export let renderedOutput = join()
```

into this js file: pre-rendered and not rendered every time when the application loads, I just want to store the results.

```
renderedOutput = "string1string2" // stores the result"string1string2"
```

I have looked at compile options for tsc, uglify, minify. I do not know exactly what it is called what I am trying to do. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this in Node.js or Browser?

Comment: @xDreamCoding The code will be shipped to the browser and everything will be run there including the template rendering, that is why I want to find a way to like pre-stage everything.